# Keras Cifar10 example data preprocessing

Tags: deep-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

In the example code, we have:
x_train /= 255
x_test /= 255

What's the benefit to downscale all RGB values to [0,1]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neural networks will train faster and numerically more stable if you feed in normalized values between 0 and 1 or -1 and 1. In general it is essential to normalize if your input data has different scales.

Since images usually have value ranges between 0-255 this normalizing step isn´t strictly necessary. See Karpathys blog post here: http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/